# CSS3 Animation chain not working in webkit browsers

Tags: css, css-animations

I can't seem to find a solution for this problem.

There's a sprite animation that I've put into a div.
Now I want 2 different movements on that containing div.

1. should bring the div into view
2. should move the div from left to right in an infinite loop

It works perfectly in FF & IE, but the 2nd animation in the chain does not play in webkit browsers....

The funny thing is that if you open the inspector in Chrome and hover over the divs in the html code, you can actually see the container and the sprite div moving, but the sprite itself doesn't. Weird...

Here's the code http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yyGJGX?editors=110

Thx in advance.

The html

```
<body>
    <section class="center">

        <div class="movingBox">
            <div class="counter"></div>
        </div>

    </section>
</body>
```

The CSS

```
.center {
    width:600px;
    height:400px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index: 0;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    margin:-200px 0 0 -325px;
    text-align:center;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.movingBox {
    width: 600px;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 50;

    -webkit-animation-name: box, box-move;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0s, 4s;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 4s, 6s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out, ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count:  1, infinite;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards, none;
    -webkit-animation-direction: normal, alternate;

    animation-name: box, box-move;
    animation-delay: 0s, 4s;
    animation-duration: 4s, 6s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out, ease-in-out;
    animation-iteration-count:  1, infinite;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards, none;
    animation-direction: normal, alternate;  
}

.counter {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 150px;
    width:160px;
    height:160px;
    display:block;  
    background:transparent url(../img/test.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
    z-index: 20;
    -webkit-animation: teller 4s steps(4) infinite;
    animation: teller 4s steps(4) infinite;
}




@-webkit-keyframes teller {
     0% {background-position: 0 0; } 
     100% {background-position: 0 -640px; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes box {
     0% {-webkit-transform: translateX(-600px); } 
     100% {-webkit-transform: translateX(0px); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes box-move {
     0% {-webkit-transform: translateX(0px); } 
     33% {-webkit-transform: translateX(100px); } 
     66% {-webkit-transform: translateX(50px); } 
     100% {-webkit-transform: translateX(350px); }
}

@keyframes teller {
     0% {background-position: 0 0; } 
     100% {background-position: 0 -640px; }
}

@keyframes box {
     0% {transform: translateX(-600px); } 
     100% {transform: translateX(0px); }
}

@keyframes box-move {
     0% {transform: translateX(0px); } 
     33% {transform: translateX(100px); } 
     66% {transform: translateX(50px); } 
     100% {transform: translateX(350px); }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### CSS Solution

After playing around, I found out, that the issue is if you try combining *two* keyframe animations with the **same** CSS properties (`-webkit-transform: translateX()`) the first one will interfere with the second one.

A working solution is to just animate the `left`-value in your first keyframe animation and afterwards use `-webkit-transform: translateX`.

```
@-webkit-keyframes box {
    0% { left: -600px; } 
    100% { left: 0; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes boxMovePlease {
    0% {-webkit-transform: translateX(0px); } 
    33% {-webkit-transform: translateX(100px); } 
    66% {-webkit-transform: translateX(50px); } 
    100% {-webkit-transform: translateX(350px); }
}
```

Comment: That seems very logical. I have tried it, but now the 1st animation doesn't work. The container div starts at -600px and stays there. It does not animate to the 100% stage of the 1st animation. I've also tried removing the 0% part, but then it starts at "left: 0" and goes straight to the 2nd animation.

Comment: you had a syntax error in your pen. you wrote `0% {left: -600px); }` it should be `0% {left: -600px; }` **without** the `)`. Here's the [pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OPrmXv) ;)